# How to add Refiners in Modern Search

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Greeting..!!

I need to add Refiners in SharePoint Modern Team site Search Results. Please check attached screenshot for better understanding.

Also, i need to configure term store terms in Refiners filter pane.

Can anyone help me for the same?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0oAX.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

based on my knowledge there is no (easy) way to change layout of default search results page.

In order to customize search in modern page there is this project: https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/

With that webparts you can create separate search center page based on your needs.

After that, change in Site/Sitecollection search setting the Search center page.